# Executing a stored procedure iIn SQL Server Agent with an automated parameter for all steps

Tags: sql-server, parameters, sql-server-agent

I have a series of stored procedures (27 in total) that I would like to execute sequentially in an automated way. I have created the required 27 job steps in SQL Server Agent (each step executing a stored procedure).

However, some of these procedures require a parameter to fill out called `LastEndOFMonthDate` where you fill out the date (ie 03/24/2018) in the parameter. This parameter would have the same value (date) for each job step. I was wondering how I could automate the parameter aspect, so that I would not have to manually enter the same parameter value for each stored procedure/job step that required it?

Here is an example of a stored procedure I am executing as one of the 27 job steps:

```
exec [dbo].[sp_05_UpdateDataMart_26_Create_JMIDataMart_With_Demo_and_Total] @LastEndOfMonthDate
```

If anyone could provide an easy way to automate the parameter aspect of this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to create 27 `steps` to execute 27 `procedures`, you can put them all in 1 `step` and calculate your `parameter` 1 time as the first row of the `step`.

You can also write a `wrapping procedure` (main) that will call all your 27 sp using the `parameter` passed in main.

If it's necessary to be able to exit the whole `job` on errors in some `procedures` and to continue in case of others, instead of 27 `steps` you can make 1 `SSIS package` with 1 parameter at the package level, and assign the correct actions on `success`/`complete`/`failure` for every 27 `ExecuteSQLTasks` within a `package`.

The last idea (requires to rewrite your procedures) is to get the `parameter` from a `table`.
Every proc should read the parameter as its first step from the same `table`. This way you can store the value `DeltaDays` (if I understood you correctly you want to execute your procs for a date "N days ago"), so you put this value in a `table` once, and all the procs read the value and calculate the correct date on their own, and you don't need to pass in anything, just schedule these procs.